# Угловой градиент как?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как подобное правильно реализовать?
Делал через картинки (но это не правильно), сама суть, чтобы поле для заливки градиента было динамичным, то есть - захотел выставил 93%, захотел 2% и тд.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Угловой градиент можно создать с помощью `conic-gradient`:

```
.pie {
  background: conic-gradient(aqua, lime);
  border-radius: 50%
}
```

Примеры других градиентов - [здесь](https://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/). И [там же](https://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/#usage) - инструкция по подключению на сайт. Дело в том, что `conic-gradient` на данный момент лишь принят W3C как часть CSS4 Images ([ссылка](https://www.w3.org/TR/css4-images/#conic-gradients)). Браузеры его пока не поддерживают. Но использовать его можно уже сейчас с помощью [полифила](https://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/#usage).

С динамичным формированием диаграммы - сложнее. В CSS популярное решение - использовать для диаграммы две заготовленные половинки окружности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И, если нужно больше 50% заполненности - используются обе половинки. Если меньше 50% - одна. Решается это установкой дополнительного класса (например, `.big`, для `.pie`).

Скорее всего, нужен будет небольшой js-скрипт, который будет смотреть, сколько %-заполненности установлено у `.pie`, и будет ставить, или не ставить, дополнительный класс.

Comment: А какая поддержка браузерами у conic-gradient?

Comment: В ответе фраза про поддержку в браузерах - ссылка: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients - но сейчас проверю в других источниках, уточню

Comment: Да, вы были правы, спасибо за подсказку. `conic-gradient` пока работает лишь с полифилом. Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Вот этот прогресс бар должен подойти https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress
Демо: http://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/

Либо найти по запросу progressbar circle